# Really simple, free Graphics software with low entry cost to export images positions

Tags: software-recommendation, open-source

I am developing simple 2D UI/Animation in SDL_image based in-house library that allows me to import images and perform simple operations (positioning, rotation ect.). The requirement is to insert multiple images and use a mechanism to position them in global coordinates. The library works fine for this purpose, but doing that is cumbersome because:

- It is not possible to snap many images to a virtual edge
- It is not possible to align images to the same center line
- It is hard to resize them (possible but not efficient)
- Each time picture parameter is changed recompilation is needed

This make me think about a software that would allow me to perform such operations and export:

- Positions of each pictures in global coordinate system
- Size of each image in pixels (height x width)

I knew there are probably many software solutions that would allow this, but I would need something easy to start with. I don't want to spend more time on learning how to use the soft than I would save by doing this by hand.

Comment: To be totally honest theres no software that you dont need time to spend learning. Realistically nearly any graphics software out there is capable of what you ask which either means youve never used any or are using software on very superficial level. Theres no such thing as no learning needed.

Comment: Maybe something like Figma, it's free.

Comment: @joojaa Yeh, I totaly agree. I don't expect zero-entry cost, but there are more and less sophisticated tools on the marked.  I have also experience with Autocad 2D/3D, may be useful heere...

Comment: @AdamStepniak in that case use that. So the rule of thumb is if you need to do x without investment in tooling then use application you allready know how to use and have installed. So i would do this in Illustrator, but i could easily do it in inkscape, powerpoint (which is actually quite okay for this), inDesign, Autocad, Rhino, Maya, 3DS Max, Blender...

Comment: I do not really understand your requirements. But I am wondering if CSS positioning would help, You can even use an excel worksheet to define the position of elements, even without the elements themselves.